# When I export glb my textures turn black

Tags: modeling, texturing, shaders, export, gltf

I'm trying to export my project to glb to put on Mozilla Hubs, but after the export process, when I up to web, my model is totally black.

what would be the problem?

Pls helpp

[image: shading][[image: rock][2]]
[image: export]
[image: hubs]

Comment: For one thing, you can't use Object Texture Coordinates in glTF. You have to unwrap your model and use UVs.

Comment: It's working now, thankss!!!

Comment: Glad it's working!  I would ask the moderators of this site, please don't close glTF / GLB questions as a duplicate of the FBX answer about materials not being very exportable.  The complex node graph shown in the OP's first screenshot here will export just fine to glTF, except for the one misplaced link to Object Texture Coordinates instead of a UV Map.  @scurest's comment here is the correct answer, and fixing that one link will make this work in glTF (but not FBX).